# таблица из блоков, полосатая зебра

Tags: html

Как сделать средством css? чтобы таблица была полосатая, первая строка черная из 6 блоков, вторая белая из 6 блоков и так далее.

```
 <div class="table">
 <div class="row">1</div>
<div class="row">2</div>
<div class="row">3</div>
<div class="row">4</div>
<div class="row">5</div>
<div class="row">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовали поискать в Google? На самом деле есть немного вариантов как это можно сделать и найти всё это довольно просто, будь то в YouTube видео урок или через Google запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Чётные строки

```
.table .row:nth-child(even){
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
```

Нечетные строки

```
.table .row:nth-child(odd){
    background: #fff;
}
```

Можно добавить стиль по порядковому номеру строк таблицы:
Строки 1,4,6...

```
.table .row:nth-child(3n+1){
    background: #f2fff5;
}
```

Строки 2,5,8...

```
.table .row:nth-child(3n+2){
    background: #ffeaea;
}
```

Строки 3,6,9...

```
.table .row:nth-child(3n+3){
    background: #eeecff;
}
```

Как лучше и проще создавать таблицы, [статья](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/kak-pravilno-verstat-html-tablicy-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo).

Comment: По моему у вас что-то не так с селекторами...

Comment: Так и у автора в примере из таблицы только класс "table".

Comment: Справедливо, но можно было бы сделать так: `.table .row:nth-child(even/odd)` и дальше по аналогии.